# Weird character in chrome when sending URL

Tags: c++, url, c++11, system-calls

I'm having some trouble while trying to open a local file in google-chrome as it gives me a weird URL in google chrome but prints just fine in the console.

Here is my code:

```
int subId = 902 ;
system(("google-chrome "+localURL+"initialFr.html?id="+to_string(subId)).data());
std::cout << ("google-chrome "+localURL+"initialFr.html?id="+to_string(subId)).data() << std::endl
```

Here is the output I get in the console:

> file:///home/lonni/Questionnaire/initialFr.html?id=902

Here is the address I get in chrome:

> file:///home/lonni/Questionnaire/initialFr.html%3Fid=902

I am using c++11 (hence the `.data()`) on ubuntu.

Would you guys know where this comes from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's just URI escaping. I don't know the ins and outs of running Chrome from the command-line, but simply run `--help` or similar to find out how to use it. Certainly, expecting Chrome to simply take your URI verbatim is a little far-fetched. :) Anyway, this ultimately has absolutely nothing to do with C++ (as you actually proved already); you could doubtless reproduce this from terminal. Therefore I suggest re-writing this as a question about command-line Chrome invocation on [SuperUser.SE] or something.

Comment: Alright I'll do just that then. Should I leave the question here anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file:` URL schema does not support HTTP schema parameter passing.  Those parameters are intended to be interpreted by an HTTP server.

If you need to pass a parameter, you can use an anchor, for example:

```
file:///home/lonni/Questionnaire/initialFr.html#902
```

Comment: er good point. So it's natural, then, that Chrome would automatically URI-escape the querystring delimiter. Because there is no querystring! :D

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It nearly works I get my # transformed into "%23"

Comment: Technically, the `file:` URL scheme does not support anchors, either. Accessing an anchor in a `file:` URL is platform/browser-dependent.